# How To Check If Two List Of Tuple's Item2 Have Similar Values?

Tags: c#, linq

If I have two Tuples structured like this:

```
List<Tuple<T, List<Student>>> listOfTuplesOne;
List<Tuple<T, List<Student>>> listOfTuplesTwo;
```

I am trying to find the `Student` objects that are similar based on a property for the `Student` object, which is `Student.Id`. So, I want to find all the matches in `List<Student>` of `listOfTuplesOne` and `List<Student>` of `listOfTuplesTwo` based on `Student.Id`.

I know this is a pretty basic question, but the LINQ is confusing me a bit.

I know I can't do something like this:

```
listOfTuplesOne.ForEach(
    x => x.Item2.Where(d => d.Id == listOfTuplesTwo.Select(
        r => r.Item2.Select(z => z.Id));
```

But it should be close to what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions that iterate one list, performing a `Contains` or `Any` on the other list are going to suffer from nasty performance characteristics as the number of comparisions grows exponentially w.r.t. the number of items.

Matching tasks are most succinctly (and efficiently, in the case of LINQ to objects) described by joins.

So, first, lets get all the students on each side of the join into single sequences. You can do this flattening with `SelectMany`:

```
var flattenedStudentsFromListOne = listOfTuplesOne.SelectMany(t => t.Item2);
var flattenedStudentsFromListTwo = listOfTuplesTwo.SelectMany(t => t.Item2);
```

Now let's join the two (non-nested) sequences together via the `Id` property:

```
var matchingStudents = flattenedStudentsFromListOne
    .Join(
        flattenedStudentsFromListTwo, 
        s1 => s1.Id, 
        s2 => s2.Id, 
        (studentOne, studentTwo) => new { studentOne, studentTwo });
```

Say, instead, you want to also find non-paired items, you'll require a `FullOuterJoin`. Sadly there is no standard implementation in LINQ, so here's a pair of extension methods that give a similar interface to the standard `Join`:

```
public static class JoinExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftSequence,
        IEnumerable<TRight> rightSequence,
        Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
        Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult> projection,
        TLeft defaultLeft = default(TLeft),
        TRight defaultRight = default(TRight),
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        var cmp = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        var leftLookup = leftSequence.ToLookup(leftKeySelector, cmp);
        var rightLookup = rightSequence.ToLookup(rightKeySelector, cmp);

        var allKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(
            leftLookup.Select(p => p.Key).Concat(rightLookup.Select(p => p.Key)),
            cmp);

        return allKeys
            .SelectMany(
                key => leftLookup[key].DefaultIfEmpty(defaultLeft),
                (key, leftItem) => new { key, leftItem })
            .SelectMany(
                x => rightLookup[x.key].DefaultIfEmpty(defaultRight),
                (x, rightItem) => projection(x.leftItem, rightItem, x.key));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftSequence,
        IEnumerable<TRight> rightSequence,
        Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
        Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> projection,
        TLeft defaultLeft = default(TLeft),
        TRight defaultRight = default(TRight),
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        return leftSequence
            .FullOuterJoin(
                rightSequence,
                leftKeySelector,
                rightKeySelector,
                (leftItem, rightItem, _) => projection(leftItem, rightItem),
                defaultLeft,
                defaultRight,
                comparer);
    }
}
```

so now you can:

```
var matchingStudents = flattenedStudentsFromListOne
    .FullOuterJoin(
        flattenedStudentsFromListTwo, 
        s1 => s1.Id, 
        s2 => s2.Id, 
        (studentOne, studentTwo) => new { studentOne, studentTwo });
```

Returned items with `null` as the value for `studentOne` or `studentTwo` represent students that didn't have a matching item on the other side of the join. Yay.

Comment: This is a pretty nice solution and I appreciated it. Is it possible to also list the ones that DON'T match as well with this approach?

Comment: @Cuphead That would require a full outer join. I'll dig out an implementation and add it to the post.

Comment: So, is there a way to actually assign the matches as a List of Students, rather than a var with this approach?

Comment: @Cuphead Sure: `matchingStudents.Select(x=>x.studentOne).ToList()` (or in the full outer join case) `matchingStudents.Where(x=>x.studentOne != null && x.studentTwo != null).Select(x=>x.studentOne).ToList()`

Comment: Cool, thank you. One last question, if I have an Id property on my T's and wanted to create a new List<Tuple<T, List<Student>> with the T being the T's that match based off the Id and the List being the matchedList of Students, is there a way to do that as well?

Comment: @Cuphead That's a very different question from that which is asked above. This is becoming a chameleon question. Take a read of this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) to understand what I mean. I feel the question, as stated is solved by the answers provided. Please open a new question if you need to ask something different.

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways to achieve that, for example first select all your students (one and two) into new collections then do:

```
var studentsOne = listOfTuplesOne.SelectMany(s => s.Item2);
var studentsTwo = listOfTuplesTwo.SelectMany(s => s.Item2);

var matchResult = studentsOne.Where(s => studentsTwo.Select(t => t.Id).Contains(s.Id));
```

Comment: Might be good for small lists, but with large lists, the O(n^2) complexity will bog things down.

Comment: @spender yes you are right, I will add some other solutions later.